# symfony 1.4/propel: problems trying to the previous element of a group of elements retrieved using a criteria

Tags: symfony1, criteria, propel

i have retrieved a group of elements using a propel criteria. Now are at `$Sedi18ns`

When i use this:

```
$SediI18ns->prev()
```

I get:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   method
>   sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator::prev()

No problems when i use `next()`.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator) has a `next()` method, as defined by [the `Iterator` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), but no `prev()` method. You can access them as arrays, and use numeric indexes, or just save the previous object in a variable and use that.